# Data from list view cannot pass to fragment

Tags: android, listview

i am trying to do a when i click on listview item , and the data of the row will pass to another fragment and show it. But now problem is the fragment is already can display but the data cannot pass.i am using bundle to set the argument.

i already found the post but not have any post help me solve this problem..

this is my list view java

```
otherAdapter adapter = new otherAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.grid_single, result);
            grid_list.setAdapter(adapter);
            grid_list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {  // list item click opens a new detailed activity
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    otherModel othermodel = result.get(position);
                    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                    bundle.putString("otherModel",new Gson().toJson(othermodel));
                    OtherDetail other = new OtherDetail();
                    other.setArguments(bundle);
                    getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container,new OtherDetail()).addToBackStack(null).commit();
                }
```

and at my fragment java i am using getArgument try to call the data.

```
Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
    if(bundle != null) {
        String json = bundle.getString("otherModel"); // getting the model from MainActivity send via extras
        otherModel otherModel = new Gson().fromJson(json, otherModel.class);
}
```

Comment: See [this link](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html) for Activity Fragment communication.

Comment: why you are not passing object of otherModel in bundle, by using putSerializable() ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must pass "other" in the transaction, you do not have to create a new fragment.
When creating the fragment in the transaction, you send it without arguments.

Answer (score 0):

> Actually the problem is, you set Argument in Different object and passing for transaction is Different, so pass the same object for both in simple word, if you set an Argument in `other` then pass same object for Transaction.

Replace this line with below code.

```
getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container,other).addToBackStack(null).commit();
```